DBT Artifacts failing in "Uploading models"
We have utilised DBT artifacts in our project to collect stats and the stats are automatically uploaded to BQ table using below
on-run-end:
  - "{{ dbt_artifacts.upload_results(results) }}"

The output looks fine & ran perfectly fine for 10-15 days. However it started failing with the error while executing "uploading models" that "The query is too large. The maximum standard SQL query length is 1024.00K characters."
On analysis , it seems like each time it is inserting stats of all models in models table irrespective of the model is getting executed or not. Due to this , the query which inserts data in this table is getting increased whenever a new model is introduced and after some time it starts failing.
Any thoughts on how to restrict the multiple time entries even if when the model is not executed or changed ?
